# Does Ransack support the same polymorhpic belongs_to associations in its searches as MetaSearch does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, meta-search, ransack

I am migrating from the MetaSearch gem to the Ransack gem for an upgrade to Rails 3.1 and I am having problems with my searches for polymorphic associations. The existing MetaSearch syntax isn't working for Ransack, but I couldn't find any documentation mentioning any syntax changes. Or whether this feature is supported in Ransack.

For example, from the MetaSearch github page, given the following classes:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  validates_presence_of :body
end
```

you can create a search field in your form like this (which is apparently a convention borrowed from Searchlogic):

```
<%= f.text_field :commentable_article_type_body_contains %>
```

I am using this type of syntax, which works perfectly in MetaSearch, but with Ransack my application is throwing an exception when the query parameter contains this field. The exception is:

```
ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError (Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :ownable)
```

Does anyone know how to do this type of search in Ransack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was struggling with the same problem (although my error was different). I think your code needs to be:

```
<%= f.text_field :commentable_of_Article_type_body_contains %>
```

note the capital A

That worked for me. You can checkout Ernie's tests for polymorphic associations [here](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/commit/c156fa4a7ac6e1a8d730791c49bf4403aa0f3af7) (it's the last file on the page)

Answer (score 2):

In my particular case, I continued to receive a NameError (uninitialized constant) even when using the appropriate ransack syntax.

## View

```
# NAME ERROR

<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <%= f.label :identifiable_of_Drug_type_name_or_description_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :identifiable_of_Drug_type_name_or_description_cont, class: 'form-control form-control-bb' %>
</div>
```

I was able to remedy this by using a ransack alias:

## Model

```
class Identifier < ApplicationRecord
  # note the missing 'cont' predicate
  ransack_alias :name_or_description, :identifiable_of_Drug_type_name_or_description
end
```

## View

```
# NO ERROR

<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  # 'cont' predicate is declared in the view
  <%= f.label :name_or_description_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :name_or_description_cont, class: 'form-control form-control-bb' %>
</div>
```