# Polymorphic filter collection: records from 2 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In ActiveAdmin, I'd like to include a filter for a polymorphic association, which in my case is called `enterable`.

That requires specifying a collection, but since - obviously - records come from multiple models in a polymorphic association I'm unsure how to combine records from multiple tables. This is clearly incorrect but you get what I'm trying to do:

```
filter :enterable, collection: [Award.all,Challenge.all], label: "Award/Challenge"
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For activeadmin < 1.0.0, take a look at https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_search#multi-level-associations.  Towards the bottom of that section, it explains how to handle polymorphic associations.

For activeadmin >= 1.0.0, see this SO question about [how to do this using ransack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077954/does-ransack-support-the-same-polymorhpic-belongs-to-associations-in-its-searche)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Entry do
  # For activeadmin < 1.0.0 , which uses meta_search
  filter :enterable_award_type_title_or_enterable_challenge_type_title

  # For activeadmin >= 1.0.0 , which uses ransack
  filter :enterable_of_Award_type_title_or_enterable_of_Challenge_type_title

  # A more programmatic approach to building this long name would be:
  filter ([Award, Challenge].collect do |enterable| 
    "enterable_of_#{enterable.to_s}_type_title" 
  end.join("_or_")).to_sym
end
```

Comment: Thanks - I've added search_method etc. to my model `Entry` but I'm getting `undefined method 'search_method' for #<Class:0x007fe748298bf0>` Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I've completely updated my answer.  I think you're using activeadmin >= 1.0.0, and my original answer was targeted at older versions.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, but with `filter :enterable_of_Award_type_title_or_enterable_of_Challenge_type_title` (title is shared between the two models) the filter doesn't appear, and the programmatic version results in this error: `undefined method 'to_sym' for #<Enumerator: ["Award", "Challenge"]:collect>` (having changed `column_name` to `:title`

Comment: I added some parens to the programmatic approach to address that error.  But I suspect you'll get the same result--all it's doing is constructing the same symbol that you tried already.

Comment: Afraid that doesn't work either `syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting ')'` many thanks for your help though.

Comment: Maybe try replacing `do` / `end` with curly braces?